# vb 2012 how do I make independent listboxes from data records?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox, linked-list

Very new to visual studio 2012.

I'm trying to select labour in the top listbox and the excavator in the bottom listbox. When I select the bottom listbox as excavator, the top listbox changes to the excavator as well. How do I make these independent?? The listboxes are looking up a data table where each resource/selection is a row/record. I only want to look up the resource record and not modify the record and the user inputs the quantity manually.

[image: Image of list boxes]

[image: Image of list boxes]

Comment: have been reading a lot and realised that i didnt have my database normalised and my relationships were bad due to this. Now I'm stuck on closing a form after the datagridview shows a lookup value in lieu of a id value

Comment: I changed the Autosizemode property for that DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from NotSet to None and the error stopped :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are binding the same object as source to these two list boxes.

If your `DataTable` name is `dt`, use `dt.AsEnumerable()` as `DataSource` to each of your list box.